# glsl texture follow cursor with three js

Tags: three.js, glsl

I made a glsl texture where the circle follows the cursor:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;


float circleshape(vec2 position, float radius){
  return step(radius, length(position - u_mouse / u_resolution));
}
void main(){
  vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;

 vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

 float circle = circleshape(position, 0.2);

 color = vec3(circle);

  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

and it works as it should.
This texture is applied to a PlaneBufferGeometry Three js and I expect the same result, but it doesn't:

```
let uniforms = { 
    u_resolution: { value: {x: window.innerHeight, y: window.innerHeight }},
    u_mouse: { value: {x: 0, y: 0 }}
}



const shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader( )
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>{
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = e.clientX
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = e.clientY
})
 
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial );

mesh.scale.set(window.innerHeight * 2, window.innerHeight, 1);

scene.add( mesh );
```

Position of circle does not match cursor position. How I can to fix it?